# SDL Not redrawing screen after Flip or Update

Tags: sdl, raspberry-pi

I recently started programming with SDL and I've been following some tutorials on gamedevgeek and lazyfoo. I got to show images on the screen, but when I tried to move them I realized the screen was not updating correctly, making the sprite leave a trace, like in this image:

[image: Picture taken from my monitor, because I don't know how to take a screenshot on a linux with no x-server installed]

As you can see, the sprite started out in the top left corner, and it left a trace throughout its path to the bottom right.

Some info that can help:

1. I'm using a raspberry pi with raspbian.
2. I'm using SDL 1.2.

What have I tried:

1. I tried changing the last parameter of SDL_SetVideoMode to SDL_HWSURFACE, SDL_SWSURFACE, SDL_DOUBLEBUF, SDL_FULLSCREEN
2. I tried to switch between SDL_Flip(screen) and SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0); when I changed the parameter of SDL_SetVideoMode.

Here is my code.

```
#include "SDL.h"

#define SCREEN_WIDTH  640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  SDL_Surface *screen, *temp, *sprite;
  SDL_Rect rcSprite;
  SDL_Event event;
  Uint8 *keystate;

  int colorkey, gameover;

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  // screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
  // screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_HWSURFACE);
  screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_SWSURFACE);

  temp   = SDL_LoadBMP("sprite.bmp");
  sprite = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
  SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

  colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 0, 255);
  SDL_SetColorKey(sprite, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY | SDL_RLEACCEL, colorkey);

  rcSprite.x = 0;
  rcSprite.y = 0;

  gameover = 0;


  while (!gameover)
  {
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
      switch (event.type) {

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
          switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
              gameover = 1;
              break;
        }
      break;
    }
  }

    keystate = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
    if (keystate[SDLK_LEFT] )
      rcSprite.x -= 2;
    if (keystate[SDLK_RIGHT] )
      rcSprite.x += 2;
    if (keystate[SDLK_UP] )
      rcSprite.y -= 2;
    if (keystate[SDLK_DOWN] )
      rcSprite.y += 2;

    SDL_BlitSurface(sprite, NULL, screen, &rcSprite);
    // SDL_Flip(screen);
    SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  SDL_FreeSurface(sprite);
  SDL_FreeSurface(grass);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Needless to say that I'm very new to the linux world, as well as the raspberry pi's, as well as SDL's :)

Comment: The smudge is proof that it is redrawing, but rather the screen is not clearing. All you need is to clear the at the start of each frame with SDL_FillRect. If your learning SDL I would suggest you start with SDL2. It has many improvements over SDL1.*.

Comment: How are you using `SDL_SetVideoMode()` in SDL2?

Comment: @genpfault well, turns out I'm not. I was re-reading the setup tutorial and the apt-get command was pointing to 1.2. I will edit my question and update the info. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call to SDL_SetVideoMode() is incorrect, your code should not compile, enable your compiler warnings.

The function takes four arguments:

```
SDL_Surface *SDL_SetVideoMode(int width, int height, int bpp, Uint32 flags);
```

so it should be something like:

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32 , SDL_SWSURFACE);
if( !screen )
    //print your warning and exit.
```

Also your screen surface is never cleared and the sprite remains. Either redraw the entire screen with sprites or clear the surface

```
SDL_FillRect( screen , NULL , 0x0 ) ;    //fills the entire surface with 0x0 .
```